# Como chamar um arquivo no node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Quero saber como chamo um arquivo.js se alguém puder explicar passo a passo agradeço.

Até onde eu entendi para chamar um arquivo externo tenho que criar uma espécie de pacote isso procede?

Answer (score 8):

Para você chamar o seu arquivo.js você precisa fazer assim;

Em arquivo.js

```
module.exports = 'olá mundo'; //Você pode exportar qualquer coisa (não apenas uma string)
```

`module` é um variavel global injetada em todos os arquivos pelo node, você pode alterar o atributo `exports` dessa variável para expor (tornar visível) o conteúdo do seu módulo. Tudo que não está atribuído a propriedade `module.exports` é privado ao módulo e portanto não é acessível externamente.

E no seu outro aquivo, app.js por exemplo:

```
var arquivo = require('./arquivo.js'); //Desde que arquivo.js esteja na mesma pasta
console.log(arquivo);
```

O pacote a que você se refere, ou seja o [package.json](http://browsenpm.org/package.json) não é necessário. É opcional mas é extremamente recomendado. Quando você evoluir um pouco mais seu conhecimento eu sugiro que deva ser a próxima coisa a se aprender, pois é com ele que você gerencia as dependências da sua aplicação com o [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) (dentre outras coisas).

A variável `require` também não veio "do nada", justamente como `module` ela é uma variável injetada pelo node que permite carregar o conteúdo do módulo. Se você aponta para um arquivo `.json` o `require` vai carregar o conteúdo deste arquivo para você (algo muito prático).

[Toda vez que você faz um require de um módulo ele é colocado em um cache](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_require_cache), ou seja, se você fizer mais de um require ao longo do seu arquivo o seu módulo é carregado apenas uma vez, portanto é comum que você encontre todos os "requires" no começo do arquivo, ou seja, você não precisa chama-lo repetidas vezes para o mesmo módulo.

#### Mais um exemplo

em Animal.js

```
module.exports = function Animal(nome, tipo) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.tipo = tipo;
}
```

em app.js

```
var Animal = require('./Animal.js'), //o `.js` é opcional! require('./Animal') também funcionaria
    peDePano = new Animal('Pé de Pano', 'Cavalo');

console.log(peDePano.tipo);
```

#### Outro Exemplo

Em dados.json:

```
{
    "site": "StackOverflow",
    "url": "pt.stackoverflow.com"
}
```

Em app.js

```
var dados = require('./dados.json');
console.log(dados.site + ': ' + dados.url);
```